# Consume Java RESTful webservice with jQuery

Tags: java, jquery, json, web-services

[image]

Consuming a RESTful Webservice with jQuery is what I want to achieve. After following this [tutorial](https://netbeans.org/kb/docs/websvc/rest.html) successfully. One of the file type is a JSON file. I want to read the values from the JSON file to be displayed on HTML file using jQuery. This is the code written so far to test this,but it is not giving the right output, what can I do?

This is the jQuery file

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $.ajax({
        url: "http://localhost:8080/WMWebServiceApplication/webresources/com.mycompany.wmwebserviceapplication"
    }).then(function(data) {
       $('.discountCode').append(data.discountCode);
       $('.rate').append(data.rate);
    });
});
```

These are the parameters of the webservice created using Java

```
URL: http://localhost:8080/WMWebServiceApplication/webresources/com.mycompany.wmwebserviceapplication.discountcode
```

JSON parameters and values

```
[{"discountCode":"H","rate":16.00},{"discountCode":"M","rate":11.00},{"discountCode":"L","rate":7.00},{"discountCode":"N","rate":0.00}]
```

Request method

```
![GET(application/json)][3]
```

Comment: If you haven't done sofar. Go and get Firebug, or use the developper tools of Chrome, set a breakpoint when you receive the data and check what you get.

Answer (score 2):

It's because you're receiving an array of objects in the JSON, so for example if you'd like to access the first element, you should write:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $.ajax({
        url: "http://localhost:8080/WMWebServiceApplication/webresources/com.mycompany.wmwebserviceapplication"
    }).then(function(data) {
        $('.discountCode').append(data[0].discountCode);
        $('.rate').append(data[0].rate);
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a way to loop through the data and retrieve all of the values - http://jsfiddle.net/jayblanchard/cb62m/

```
for(i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    $('.discountCode').append(data[i].discountCode + ' ' + data[i].rate + '<br />');
}
```